# Force a leading zero to show on page for input type="text" for time format hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, html, css, markup

HTML markup `<input type="text" value="00:00:00" class="datepicker-time" aria-invalid="false">` does not display the leading zero in a text input with time format hh:mm:ss. Even though the value for the input is 00:00:00, the page shows 0:00:00. How can I force the leading zero to display?

Comment: When you put just that element on [a page](https://jsfiddle.net/acxpt3zn/), you get 00:00:00.

Comment: You are using the wrong `input`... use `<input type="time">` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulie_D said - use `type='time'` instead of text..

`<input type="time" value="00:00" class="datepicker-time" aria-invalid="false"/>`

One thing to note is that [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) has a lot of good info on how you can use this, both in `JS` and the general `HTML` items.